# How to update Databricks secrete via databricks python notebook?

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

I want to update databricks secrete programmatically via python notebook.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#get-command-dbutilssecretsget) and AFAIK that's not possible.

You will have to use the CLI for that.